# How to sort and merge lists using scala?

Tags: scala, sorting, merge

I have two different lists which contains different data.
Here is a example of lists-

```
list1:[{"name":"name1","srno":"srno1"},{"name":"name2","srno":"srno2"}]
list2:[{"location":"location1","srno":"srno2"},{"location":"location2","srno":"srno1"}]
```

These two lists have a field in common that is 'srno' which is of type string.
I want to map lists on srno and merge these two lists such that record corresponding to 'srno:1' from list1 to 'srno:1' to list2.

So file list would be like this:

```
[{"name":"name1","srno":"srno1","location":"location2"},{"name":"name2","srno":"srno2","location":"location2"}]
```

How do I sort and merge these two lists to form a single list using scala?

**Edit:**
There will be one to one correspondance i.e. srno1 will be present exactly once in both the lists

Comment: Is there a one-to-one correspondence between the lists, or can there be some values of `srno` on one list that don't appear in the other?

Comment: There will be one to one correspondance

Comment: Your notation does not look like Scala. Are you manipulating JSON data? If yes, what library do you use? If not, can you give the type of `list1`?

Comment: I am processing json data. I want to make single list from two different lists. I am doing it in play framework by importing package - play.api.libs.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are converting your json to case classes, you can use for comprehension to do this.

```
case class NameSrno(name: String, srno: String)
case class SrnoLoc(srno: String, location: String)
case class All(name: String, srno: String, location: String)

def merge(nsl: List[NameSrno], sll: List[SrnoLoc]): List[All] = {
  for {
    ns <- nsl
    sl <- sll
    if (ns.srno == sl.srno)
  } yield All(ns.name, ns.srno, sl.location)
}
```

Usage:

```
val nsl = List(NameSrno("item1", "1"), NameSrno("item2", "2"))
val sll = List(SrnoLoc("1", "London"), SrnoLoc("2", "Tokyo"))

 merge(nsl, sll)
//> res0: List[test.SeqOps.All] = List(All(item1,1,London), All(item2,2,Tokyo))
```

Comment: O(N^2), though. If the lists are short that's fine. Otherwise, sort them on the value of srno, zip them together and do a linear merge for O(n log n)

Comment: I agree. OTOH, I don't see how this can be more efficient with just lists.

Comment: In practice, the lists will be short, I expect